# Model\User not found

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to retrieve information on Users using the [Microsoft Graph Library for PHP](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php.).

I can see that in `GraphResponse.php`, my `$result` is filled with correct data but the code does not find the `Model\User-class`.

```
$user = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/users")
              ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
              ->execute();
```

Since I am not familiar with this autoload-thing, I am stuck. Any help appreciated.

Is there any better documentation for this subject???

Comment: Did you add `use Microsoft\Graph\Model;`?

Comment: of course I did NOT ;-). Thx so lot. I'll have a look at the new problem that came up.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're experiencing some troubles with installing  `msgraph-sdk-php` package and that's the reason why `Model\User` type could not be resolved in your case. If you are following the official [Getting Started](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/wiki/Getting-Started) documentation, there is a typo regarding *package name* in [Installation section](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/wiki/Getting-Started#installation):

```
{
    "require": {
        "Microsoft/Graph": "^1.0"
    }
}
```

and while installing you should get the error like this

> The requested package microsoft/graph could not be found in any
>   version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Instead of `Microsoft/Graph` the *valid name* should be **`microsoft/microsoft-graph`**, for example:

```
{
    "require": {
        "microsoft/microsoft-graph": "^1.6"
    }
}
```

Once the package is installed *successfully*, the minimal example for retrieving users could look like this:

```
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use \Microsoft\Graph\Graph;

$accessToken = "--YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN-GOES-HERE--";

$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);

$user = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/users")
    ->setReturnType(\Microsoft\Graph\Model\User::class)
    ->execute();
```